# Deactivating path to a node

Tags: netlogo

I am developing a casualty rescue model. The idea behind the model is for the rescuers to search and rescue casualties. The rescuers select the casualty they are closest to at the start of their run. Next, the network extension's `nw:weighted-distance-to` function is used to find the path with the minimum distance between them.

A bit of background behind how I've implemented the model,

I have created a bunch of nodes(breed) and placed casualties(breed) and rescues(breed) on these nodes. The rescuers at the start of the model pick the closest casualty to them and select a path using `nw:weighted-distance-to`

The problem I am having is that I want to temporarily disable access to a certain path. So that the rescuers will have to get to their respective casualty using an alternative path. What I am thinking is to have a variable called accessible? (nodes-owned) and set this to false to temporarily disable access to that particular route. But I am unsure how to implement this since the network extension does not contain any function that I know that returns alternative paths.

Any Ideas?

```
extensions [nw]
let dist_list []

foreach rescuer-nodes-list [
  rescue-node ->
  foreach casualties-nodes-list[
    casualty-node ->
    ask rescue-node[
      let dist-to-casualty-node nw:weighted-distance-to casualty-node netlogo-dist
      set dist-list lput dist-to-casualty-node dist-list
    ]
  ]
]
```

The following code iterates over all nodes containing rescue agents and casualty agents and computes the minimum distance between each agent pair (rescue-casualty).

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: I have little experience with the nw extension.  But, would putting a zero weight on a link with other links having a weight of (say) one, essentially close that link to the distance calculation?

Comment: I managed to sort this by typing `ask link <number1 number2>[die]`. Then recreating the link later. `ask node <number1>[create-link-with node <number2>]` But @Charles I like your method more. Thanks !. Also in my case by adding a very large value i.e 9999 will make the path ineffective. As its longer than all other alternate paths.